# How do I align the endpoints of my input-fields in form, using css?

Tags: html, css, styling

I am making a copy of a pen-and-paper character sheet for a RPG, as a way of learning html/css. However I got stuck right at the beginning when trying to style a form, holding some background information about the character.

[image: picture of how the form looks vs how I want it]

Currently I've managed to make my form of labels and input-fields to look like the picture to the left. However the pen-and-paper character sheet (and the desired look) is formatted like the one on the right.

Below is the code I'm using.

```css
.sheet-character-background form input,
label {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.age-input {
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sheet-character">
  <div class="sheet-character-background">
    <form>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="attr_name">
      <br>
      <label>Race</label>
      <input type="text" name="attr_race">
      <br>
      <label>Gender</label>
      <input class="gender-input" type="text" name="attr_gender">
      <label>Age</label>
      <input class="age-input" type="number" name="attr_age" min="0">
      <br>
      <label>Religion</label>
      <input type="text" name="attr_religion">
      <br>
      <label>Occupation</label>
      <input type="text" name="attr_occupation">
      <br>
      <label>Archetype</label>
      <input type="text" name="attr_archetype">
      <br>
      <label>Environment</label>
      <input type="text" name="attr_environment">
      <br>
      <label>Background</label>
      <input type="text" name="attr_backgrund">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

What are the steps for going from what I have to what I want? I played around with surrounding each "row" with a `<div>` and class and setting their width in css. However this didn't work out so I reverted to my initial version and got stuck.

Comment: Are you using any framework ??

Comment: If you are not using any frame work then I think you should use table concept of html5. That will fulfill your requirements.

Comment: Use table is not a best practice, and hurt on SEO. Always use css to separate your presentation from content.

Comment: No I'm not using any framework. My idea is that the character sheet will eventually be used on roll20.net so I don't know if any frameworks are going to be compatible (and also due to lack of knowledge about the usage of frameworks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people would probably suggest to get a css framework, but what you want can be done with some simple css.

First, your html basically consists of a form with a series of rows, except for one row where it consists of two fields in one row. So I modified your html slightly that each row is wrapped by a div with a class as `.form-row` and delete the `<br>` (let css to do the rendering instead of using html tag):

To achieve what you want will then come down to set a width for the `form`, and how each `row` will behave, and set the width of `input`, and last override the setting for the special case of `.age-input`.

This is just a 'quick-and-dirty' way to achieve what you want, hopefully it provide you some ideas and suggestions in your learning.

```css
form {
    width: 300px;
}
.form-row {
    display:flex;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
}
.age-input {
    width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="attr_name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Race</label>
        <input type="text" name="attr_race">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Gender</label>
        <input type="text" name="attr_gender">
        <label>Age</label>
        <input class="age-input" type="number" name="attr_age" min="0">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Religion</label>
        <input type="text" name="attr_religion">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Occupation</label>
        <input type="text" name="attr_occupation">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Archetype</label>
        <input type="text" name="attr_archetype">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Environment</label>
        <input type="text" name="attr_environment">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Background</label>
        <input type="text" name="attr_backgrund">
    </div>
</form>
```